# what is the linear system on a cubic surface giving the blow-down map to the plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider $X$ a smooth cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$, and let $l_1,...,l_6$ be six disjoint lines contained in $X$.

What is the linear system giving the blow-down map $X \to \mathbb{P}^2$, so that the lines $l_k$ are contracted to points ?

The other way round is well-known : if $p_1,\dots,p_6$ are six points in general position, the rational map $\mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^3$ obtained by the linear system of cubic containing the six points has image a cubic surface.

Comment: In what terms? How do you describe the Picard group of $X$?

Comment: For example, one can take the base given by Hartshorne in the book "algebraic geometry", the chapter on cubic surfaces, this is given by the hyperplane section h, and the six exceptional curves.

Comment: Then your map is given by the linear system $\lvert h \rvert$…

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Your "hyperplane section", is apparently π*, via the blow down map π, of the class of a line in P^2, Hartshorne p. 401, Notation 4.7.3.  Hence it is by definition the linear series defining the blow down map.  Alternatively, since the inverse map is given by cubic plane curves with base points, the image in P^3 of a line by this map, must be the divisor you want.  The class of this rational cubic curve on X can be represented by a line m on X and two disjoint exceptional lines e1, e2, meeting m, e.g. I.e. then m + e1 + e2 ≈ π* of a line in P^2 meeting 2 blownup pts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably know, if a representation of $X$ as blowup is given,
$$
K_X = -3h + \sum l_i,
$$
where $h$ is the line class. Consequently, the linear system
$$
|-K_X + \sum l_i|
$$
gives the required contraction.

Comment: I do not see the consequence, can you explain please ?

Comment: Just observe that all divisors in this linear system are pullbacks from the plane.

Comment: Thank you ; following abx idea it is rather $|-K_X+\sum l_i|$ but divided by $3$.

Comment: These two define the same contraction.

Comment: yes, thank you (using your divisor is the map to $\mathbb{P^2}$ followed by a Veronese embedding)